# change in hook state not updating value in template literals

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to hooks and is coming after learning react with classes, so a bit lost. in the below code I am changing setDog to Husky which should then tell the API call to search and fetch me pic of a husky. But its not happening despite the change in dog. Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function ApiCalls() {
    const [ data, setData ] = useState();
    const [ dog, setDog ] = useState('labrador');

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const result = await axios(`https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${dog}/images`);
            setData(result.data.message[0]);
        };
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    const Husky = () => {
        setDog('husky');
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <img alt={''} src={data} />
            <button onClick={Husky}>Retrieve Husky</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your useEffect sensivitylist is [], so this useEffect just run on component mount that the dog variable is `labrador`. So after you change dog on button click nothings new will be fetched from server. Change your code as follow:

```
useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const result = await axios(`https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${dog}/images`);
            setData(result.data.message[0]);
        };
        fetchData();
  }, [dog]);
```

Comment: Works! Thanks buddy!

Comment: @Kisho i was the first one to answer the correct way, Why you unmarked my answer as accepted (look at my answer time and other answers time)???

Comment: Glad could to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

`useEffect` only run once because the dependency array is `[]` empty. So when you change `dog` it wont trigger. To fix this add `dog` to useEffect dependency

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function ApiCalls() {
    const [ data, setData ] = useState();
    const [ dog, setDog ] = useState('labrador');

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const result = await axios(`https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${dog}/images`);
            setData(result.data.message[0]);
        };
        fetchData();
    }, [dog]);

    const Husky = () => {
        setDog('husky');
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <img alt={''} src={data} />
            <button onClick={Husky}>Retrieve Husky</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Works! Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```js
const fetchData = async (input) => {
  const result = await axios(`https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${input}/images`);
  setData(result.data.message[0]);
};
useEffect(() => fetchData(dog), []);
```

Comment: @Kisho Great, don't forget to mark the right answer and upvote

Comment: Are you sure this gonna work??? It's not working, useEffect capture dog value at mount that is stale.